# jQuery plugin show image

Tags: image, onclick

I generate a HTML page with the links to images from a directory.

First I was thinking to load/display all the images and then to hide them using jQuery `.hide()` When a user will click to a image  I'll display that image, but I hope you can offer me a better approach.

It's possible to load/show a image, only when the user clicks to a link? Can you recommend me a plugin or a PHP script for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Ibox](http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/) and do something like this:

```
<a href="http://site.com/img.jpg" rel="ibox">Image 1</a>
```

When someone clicks this link, the image will show up in a small hovering window.

Answer (score 1):

lighbox, ThickBox would do the trick.

Look at this under Lightbox Techniques:
[Lightbox Techniques](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/15/45-new-jquery-techniques-for-a-good-user-experience/)